# Is there a string length limit for php curl return value?

Tags: php, json, curl, substr

I have a piece of php code to curl an API endpoint, it returns a json string.
But the string is chopped off to be 16042 characters long, so my json_decode function fails due to invalid format json string.

**My question is "Is there a limit for the curl return value ? "**

```
    $ch = curl_init ();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );       
    $output = curl_exec ( $ch );
    $header_size = curl_getinfo ( $ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE );
    $body = substr ( $output, $header_size );
```

**Or is the substr function chopping it off ?**

Comment: `$body = substr ( $output, $header_size );` Why this line ??

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI The return message includes the header "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: openresty/1.9.3.1 Date: Wed, 28 Dec 2016 06:07:14 GMT Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 802244 Connection: keep-alive Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Expires: -1 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true " Just need the body

Comment: don't do that.. check if the `$output` is valid json

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI That's not the case, I have verified. $output includes the header string I commented above, when I request to return 20 records, the $body gets the valid json message, but it's chopped if I request 1000 records. I also tried to var_dump($output ), the value is also chopped.

Comment: Increasing the time out value from 5 secs may help

Comment: @NadirLatif Tried to increase it to 60 seconds, same issue

Comment: If you access the url from a web browser does it show all the content ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init ();
$timeout = 60;
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );      
$output = curl_exec ( $ch );
echo $output;
```

**Exaplanation**

The `CURLOPT_HEADER` includes the header in the output. Need to set it to `false` or remove it. Click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for reference.

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always add an explanation what the code does and why it solves the problem.